# No option to enable wifi ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on a laptop but cannot enable wifi.I then ran ubuntu 16.04 on a USB and the wifi option appeared but the next time i ran it, the wifi option didnt appear.

Enable networking option is the only one in existence.

The command below produces the result shown

```
b@b-HP-Notebook:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804a]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Recommend you to check similar issues ex: [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459366/cant-detect-or-enable-the-wifi-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1)

Comment: @Egrimo The question you linked doesn't have any answer :/

Comment: Try running from terminal `systemctl restart network-manager.service`

Comment: b@b-HP-Notebook:~$ systemct1 restart network-manager.service
systemct1: command not found

Comment: the above line is the result

Comment: @M.Becerra Hmm. A 3 year old question with no answers - might as well get rid of it!

Comment: I would guess that you are missing a driver for your wifi card. Can you look at `additional drivers` (it's a GUI program, so just type this in the menu and you should find it) or run `ubuntu-drivers devices` in a terminal and show the output?

Comment: this is the result @ Sethos II

Comment: == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.4/0000:01:00.0 ==
model    : BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
vendor   : Broadcom Corporation
modalias : pci:v000014E4d00004365sv0000103Csd0000804Abc02sc80i00
driver   : bcmwl-kernel-source - third-party non-free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0 ==
model    : Kabini [Radeon HD 8240]
vendor   : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
modalias : pci:v00001002d00009838sv0000103Csd00008137bc03sc00i00
driver   : fglrx - third-party non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-ati - distro free builtin recommended
driver   : fglrx-updates - third-party non-fr

Comment: You typed it wrong, it's an lowcase L not a number 1, copy and paste it, to be sure.

Comment: systemctl command is not found @ M. Becerra

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output of `ubuntu-drivers device` I would say you are missing the driver for your wifi card. Install the package listed by `ubuntu-drivers device`:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and reboot. Afterwards the wifi card should be recognised.

Comment: b@b-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for b: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb libisl10 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-signed-image-generic-lts-xenial
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75 not upgraded.

Comment: thats the result @Sethos II

Comment: The correct driver seems to be installed. Did you reboot after installing it?

Comment: i did reboot @ Sethos II

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl`? Also, please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: b@b-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.

Answer (score 0):

On one of my systems, there's no problem with missing drivers, only the networking icon is missing from the taskbar. I can open a terminal and run:

```
sudo nm-applet
```

That works around the problem.  Then I can click on the icon, view the list of wifi networks, choose one, set it up, and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed updates from the software updater and now I can access the option for enabling Wi-Fi.To everybody for your contributions @ Sethos II @ M. Becerra @ chili555

Answer (score 0):

There may be chances that your system may be missing some wifi drivers so try to follow below command -

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

(Install the package listed by ubuntu-drivers device via above command)

and reboot .
P.S. -To download above package try to connect internet via thethring.(eg mobile phone)
Hope this helps!!