# No option for enabling wifi in ubuntu 16.04 after dualbooting it with Windows 10 in hp-Notebook

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, drivers, wireless

Its been a long searching for a solution to enable wifi in my hp-Notebook laptop after i dual booted ubuntu along with windows 10 but all in vain.

Now before some of you downvote this question and flag it as dublicate i must tell you that I tried answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459366/cant-detect-or-enable-the-wifi-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152157/enable-wireless-option-is-disabled-in-network-settings), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04) ,  many other links, sources, videos and what not, but nothing worked so far. I have lost hope but still seeking a great answer from an angel and intelligent mind to get me out of this desperate situation.

The funny part is, the same worked in virtual box without any error. Every thing was fine but now its not the same.

If somebody needs any further information regarding anything, please let me know i will provide you all the information you need.
I have tried the things in additional driver but that too in vain.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
speedious@speedious:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel modules: wl
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

speedious@speedious:~$ sudo modprobe wl
[sudo] password for speedious: 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: any idea @Pilot6 ?

Comment: Please post output of `sudo modprobe wl`.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: will try that @pilot6 . Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Disable it in BIOS, don't run any commands.

Comment: What's the output of `lshw -C network`?

Comment: @NerdOfLinux Why are you asking? Everything is clear. It won't give any information.

Comment: @Pilot6 You did turn out to be an angel. Finally, the problem is solved. I am really grateful to you.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the question. You can click on a link that you agree that the question is a duplicate.